# Python iterator class returns always the initial state of a dictionary object. Why?

Tags: python, iterator

```
class C:
 def __init__(self):
  self.ii={ 'c':0, 't':"kkk" }

 def __iter__(self):
   return self

 def __next__(self):
   if self.ii['c']>5:
     self.ii['c']=0
     raise StopIteration

   self.ii['c']+=1
   print(self.ii)
   return self.ii


x=C()

for i in x:
    pass

print([i for i in x])
```

I thought, the `print([i ...])` will show a list with increasing value in the 'c' field. But instead it shown six pieces of the initial { 'c':0, 't': 'kkk' }.

O.K., I know, that I can make it working by adding `.copy()` to the `return self.ii` but I'd like to know, what happens when there is no copy().
I can accept if it gives me a list with `{ 'c':6, 't':'kkk' }`, because the dictionaries are handled by address, not by value, but this... I can't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list you're building with your comprehension statement consists of six references to the same dict (x.ii).  It's not the "original" dict, it's the dict after your `__next__` resets `self.ii['c']` to `0`.

If your list comprehension captures the value of `i['c']` before it gets reset, you'll get different values:

```
>>> print([i['c'] for i in x])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

You can observe the issue with your original list comprehension capturing six identical references by changing one of them:

```
>>> y = [i for i in x]
>>> y[0]['test'] = 'foobar'
>>> y[1]['c'] = 42
>>> x.ii
{'c': 42, 't': 'kkk', 'test': 'foobar'}
>>> y
[{'c': 42, 't': 'kkk', 'test': 'foobar'}, {'c': 42, 't': 'kkk', 'test': 'foobar'}, {'c': 42, 't': 'kkk', 'test': 'foobar'}, {'c': 42, 't': 'kkk', 'test': 'foobar'}, {'c': 42, 't': 'kkk', 'test': 'foobar'}, {'c': 42, 't': 'kkk', 'test': 'foobar'}]
```

As you observed, changing your `__next__` to return a **copy** of the dict rather than a shared reference makes it impossible for this to happen.

Comment: Thanks! I accidentally left that resetting there... Now I understand why is it showing zeroes :)